# Login screen for a Ext JS 4.0.7 application

Tags: authentication, extjs

I've developed an Ext JS 4.0.7 app for my company. It has various modules for different team's needs. Now, the company want to make sure only relevant people have access to relevant modules in an app. It's an ERP application which has CRM, MRP, Engineering, HR and Finance modules. Now, respective team members should have access to respective menus and pages and super admin will have access to everything.

I know how to control the menus based on user login. But not sure how to integrate user login screen into my app. I know basics of Ext JS and able to design a Login screen using form panel ...... but not sure how to make it as my app's first screen and upon successful login, let the user in and able to logout from there.

If anyone already developed such functionality, i request to share the solution here. Any pointers or code snippets will be a great help.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, routing to the login form best thing to pass backend.

Comment: I'm not clear on how to do it. Can you please elaborate? What I want is: when users hit the app url, it takes them to login screen and only upon successful login, they will be able to access the app, menus and pages. Based on login user, user menus and pages will be customized based on role.

Comment: You must do next steps:
1. Create a endpoint which get login/pass
2.1. If login/pass correct - send 301 HTTP code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301 with path to you main app. (app before authenticate must be unavailable)
2.2. If login/pass incorrect - return 500 with error
This is generally a job for the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application has a header (company logo and app title - horizontal on north) and left menu and content panel.

So, here is how login/logout screen implemented.

When app is loaded, when viewport is loaded, on render, I load menu store and load 'Login' and 'Change Password' menu items in them.

When user enters login/pwd, via ajax call , will call servlet and process login data. Upon login successful, based on user role, respective menu json built in server side and menu store is loaded with this json. This json has 'Logout' menu by default. So, when user logs out, will load Login screen in content panel.

Not sure whether any other best ways to implement the same. But this is working well.